# Anyone know what a soft reboot is on the pi pico?

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico

My problem is that every time I run my python code for the pi pico it always says "MPY: soft reboot" and I have no idea on how to fix it.

I have tried many tutorials in the past 5 hours and all of them seem to not work.

Comment: Some info-
https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/3274

Answer (score 3):

on thonny click run- configure interpreter
on that menu there will be a check box at the bottom (restart before running script)
Untick the box

Comment: it'd be useful to explain what the soft reboot notice is about and why it's ok to just untick this option in Thonny.